# How to revert one commit from a reintegrated branch?

Tags: svn, version-control

Using svn 1.8.9.

I know how to revert a commit with

```
 svn merge -c -rREV filename
```

but is it possible to do this if REV is part of a branch reintegration?  My "svn log -g" on my trunk reads:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------  
r55825 | karin_lin | 2014-09-02 14:08:50 -0400 (Tue, 02 Sep 2014) | 1 line  

reintegrate dev branch 
------------------------------------------------------------------------  
r55818 | karin_lin | 2014-09-02 13:43:56 -0400 (Tue, 02 Sep 2014) | 1 line  
Merged via: r55825  

I want to revert this commit
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r55410 | karin_lin | 2014-08-22 17:34:37 -0400 (Fri, 22 Aug 2014) | 1 line
Merged via: r55825

this commit is good
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since the branch history is preserved, I would expect to be able to do "svn merge -c -55818" as usual, but it doesn't work --- the file remains unchanged.

I think I could revert all of r.55825 and restore 55410 and its predecessors, but there are quite a few.  Is there any way just to revert the 55818 part of 55825? (The branch itself was deleted, as is correct practice after reintegration.)